# How to access child controls inside inherited class?

Tags: class, inheritance, user-interface, grid

Here is what I'm doing, I have a large amount of reports, rather than copy and pasting the repeated code, I have the following..

```
public class ReportPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
  // Code
}
```

My report Pages have

```
public class MyReportPage : ReportPage
{
}
```

Problem I'm having is, I want to be able to access a control inside MyReportPage within ReportPage, for instance, I want all pages grid to have a specific property.

Inside ReportPage I tried

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  var obj = this.FindControl("reportGridName");
}
```

But unable to find the control, went through all the controls to see if I could it in, no luck..

Any ideas how to get the grid access on the inherit?

Answer (score 0):

```
Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;         
var obj = page.FindControl("reportGridName");
```

Does that work? I'm having the exact same problem and stumbled upon [this link](http://niitdeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/10/access-page-control-from-class-file-in.html)